# Is there a shorthand for setting several array elements to the same value at array instantiation?

Tags: php, arrays

So I have to construct a PHP Array;

For instance this array has four values; four keys with two unique values.

In standard PHP this can be done thus:

```
$a = $c = "value 1";
$b = $d = "second value";
```

**Is there a way of doing this sort of code reduction when instantiating a PHP array?**

I have an array with keys `starta`, `startb` and `enda`, `endb` and I want each of these two "start" and "end" keys to take the same value.

For example, I have tried just to test a few things:

```
$array =  ['starta', 'startb' => $updater['kickoff'], 'enda', 'endb' => $updater['finished'] ];

$array =  ['starta' = 'startb' => $updater['kickoff'], 'enda' = 'endb' => $updater['finished'] ];

$array =  ['starta' => 'startb' => $updater['kickoff'], 'enda' => 'endb' => $updater['finished'] ];
```

But these all return expected syntax errors.

Expected output would be:

> ```
>  array { 
>      'starta' => $updater['kickoff'],
>      'startb' => $updater['kickoff'],
>      'enda'   => $updater['finished'],
>      'endb'   => $updater['finished']   
>    }
> ```

**Why?**

I was needing to do this in one line in the array instantiation aspect of an external function

```
// Shape:
$externalClass->function($data, $array);

// Example:
$externalClass->function($data, ['starta', 'startb' => $updater['kickoff'], 'enda', 'endb' => $updater['finished'] ]);
```

I did look on [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) but no indication this is possible.

I suspect this doesn't exist as any sort of shorthand but wanted to check in case I've missed it?

Comment: [In two steps](https://3v4l.org/Xjmp3)

Comment: @Syscall I was needing to do this in one line in the array instantiation aspect of an external function

Comment: You can prepare your array, then pass it to the function. `$array=[...]; $class->func($data, $array);`

Comment: Yes, that's what I do currently. I was just curious if there was a shorthand for this as there is for elements outside of an array, as you mention in your link